# Is the cuspidal curve $\mathcal{M}$ is a coarse moduli space for lines in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

As the question suggests, is the cuspidal curve $\mathcal{M}$ a coarse moduli space for lines in $\mathbb{C}^2$? I'm inclined to believe the answer is no, but all attempts at proving it so far have seemed not fruitful...

Comment: What have you tried so far? The coarse moduli scheme has, by definition, a certain universal property. Is it satisfied by the cuspidal curve?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the moduli problem. Is it 'lines through the origin' (which would be parametrised by $\mathbb{P}^1$) or really 'all lines in $\mathbb{C}^2$' (which should result in something two-dimensional)?

Comment: Here is a hint for the case of all lines in the plane: a line in $\mathbb{C}^2$ corresponds, via the standard embedding of the plane into $\mathbb{P}^2$, to certain one-dimensional linear subspaces. Every one-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}^2$ either meets the (projective) line at infinity at precisely one point, or it is the whole line at infinity, so...

Answer (score 1):

So, I assume you mean "lines through the origin" because otherwise, a dimension count suffices (lines are $ax+by+c=0$ and so have three parameters, but modulo a $\mathbb{C}^\times$ gives a $2$ dimensional family). A quick, but admittedly non-rigorous (though it can be made rigorous) way to see that it is not is that the moduli space of lines through the origin in $\mathbb{C}^2$ must be smooth, because there are automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^2$ that swap any two lines through the origin, thus the automorphism group of the moduli space of them acts transitively, and so it is smooth.